# Sorry to interrupt: Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() when opening a child record

Tags: lightning-experience

We have 2 objects, Contact and Project Contact. Project Contact is a child of Contact. We are able to navigate directly to the Project Contact whilst the Contact record is also loaded in the background. The error occurs when we attempt to navigate from the child Project Contact to the parent Contact.

[image: Sorry to interrupt Error]

The error first occurred yesterday and, to the best of my knowledge, we have not modified any custom code relating to either object for at least a month now. The error seems to mention a workspace manager JavaScript file, however I do not seem to have access to a file by that name in Visual Studio.

Upon further investigation, it seems as though the error occurs anytime a parent record is accessed in the same way as described above and is not limited to the aforementioned objects.

I was simply wondering if anyone has encountered an error such as this one or would be willing to point out something I have missed. If you need more information on the subject feel free to reach out and I will get back to you as quickly as I can. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please check the source code it seems you are trying to set some attribute of undefined this.Obj.someVal[0].something = something; either Obj or someval is undefined. Also, enable lightning debug mode for better debugging

Comment: All the Javascript code referred to under "Technical Stuff" is from Salesforce. Salesforce's Javascript files are not downloaded to VS Code, but you can see them for example in the DevTools of a Chrome browser. Please add to your question an exact description how you navigate from the child object to the parent object. (Click on a regular link in the "Hightlights Panel"?) If I were you (and you have the possibility to do so), I'd remove elements (page elements, tabs etc.) from the target flexipage and hope that at some point the error disappears and the culprit is thereby found.

Comment: @FelixvanHove Thanks for the input. I realize this issue has a wide variety of possible problems, and the ambiguity of our own org certainly doesn't help with debugging. I will begin removing elements from the page to track down the guilty party. In the mean time, I will ask around for the specifics regarding how the problem is produced (As I am not very often in the front end of our org, I'm sure someone else would be able to give a much better explanation of how the issue is recreated). I should hopefully be posting an update to the issue soon. Thanks again for the response.